# A vector of matrices using eigen library

Tags: c++

using the Eigen library:

I want to create a vector of 4x4 matrices

then loop over it to print an output matrix

THE PROBLEM IS: in the for loop: matrices_vector.size()=0 although I filled matrices_vector with 3 matrices

Thanks all

```
//Main
vector<MatrixXd> matrices_vector;


    MatrixXd temp(4,4);
    for(int i= matrices_vector.size()-1; i=0; i--)
    {   
        temp= matrices_vector.at(i-1) * matrices_vector.at(i);
        matrices_vector.at(i-1)=temp;
        matrices_vector.erase(matrices_vector.end(),matrices_vector.end()-1);
    }
    cout<< temp;
```

Comment: I edited the post clarifying..

Comment: Show the code that fills the vector. Theres a big chance theres something wrong with it

Comment: I added the matrices_vector.pushback in the code above.. Thanks

Comment: `for(int i= matrices_vector.size()-1; i=0; i--)`  Do you see something wrong with the middle condition?

Comment: i guess not as it will stop looping if reached the beginning of the vector..

Comment: @codeZ - The middle condition is tested for `true` to keep the loop going.  If `i` is not 0, that loop never executes.

Comment: @codez - You're going backwards in the loop.  Your condition to keep looping is `i > 0`.

Comment: tried i>0 .. it DID enter the loop .. great .. but the last line  matrices_vector.erase(matrices_vector.end(),matrices_vector.end()-1   breaks

Comment: @codez - Yes the last line.  You are changing the size of the vector while you're looping over the vector.  You do see that this will totally mess up the `for` loop conditions, correct?  You're stating that "I will loop x times", but your container is shrinking at the same time you're looping, so "x times" is too big.

Comment: @codez - Why do you need to erase each time?  Why not defer erasing until you're outside the loop?

Comment: figured it out.. Thanks alot for your useful answers @PaulMcKenzie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect, as the loop will never execute if `i` is not 0.

```
for(int i= matrices_vector.size()-1; i=0; i--)
```

This should be

```
for(int i= matrices_vector.size()-1; i > 0; i--)
```

Additionally, you should check for the `matrices_vector` being empty before entering the loop, as `matrices_vector.size() - 1` will yield an invalid value if `matrices_vector.empty()` is `true`.

Also, since your loop checks for pairs, you need to enforce that there are is at least 2 items in the vector before proceeding.